# How can we remove SQL error code 1405 in C

Tags: sql, c, oracle, error-handling

I have written following piece of code in C:

```
EXEC SQL begin declare section;
    int     A;
    char    B[5];
    int     C;
    int     D;
    dtime_t E;
    char    F[13];
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;
char E_dt[16];
D=0;
memset(F, 0, sizeof(F));          

EXEC SQL declare log3 cursor for select A, B, C, D, E, F from tbl WHERE C=123;
if(sqlca.sqlcode) 
{
    return;
}

EXEC SQL fetch log3
    into
     :A, :B, :C, :D, :E, :F, 
if(sqlca.sqlcode) 
{
    if (sqlca.sqlcode != DB_NORECORDS) 
    {
        return;
    }
    break;
}
```

When we run this piece of code, where the value of F is Null in the table tbl. It gives error code 1405. I have tried memset function for setting its default value as 0. But it did not work. And one more thing can i fetch more than 90 field at a time, when i was trying to do that it gives me Bus Error at the time of compilation. Thanks in advance please help me out.

Comment: What about unsafe_null=yes or indicator variables? http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/Oracle/Q_20908570.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 basic options:

1. Use an indicator to record the presence of the NULL. You probably should use this option when you want a specific action to be taken when a NULL arises.
2. Use the NVL function to convert the retrieved NULL to another value, such as zero or blank. This is the simplest solution.

**Edit:**

Example with NVL for log3 cursor. Choose whatever default values you want. In the example I have used ' ' for character fields, 0 for numeric fields and Jan 1st year 1 for dates.

```
EXEC SQL declare log3 cursor for select NVL(A, 0), 
                                        NVL(B, ' '), 
                                        NVL(C, 0), 
                                        NVL(D, 0), 
                                        NVL(E, to_date('0001', 'YYYY')),
                                        NVL(F, ' ')
                                   from tbl 
                                  WHERE C=123;
```

Comment: Thanks Klas, I have used NVL, but it also did not work, Can you give me example of NVL functions. I am fetching more that 90 fields so 1st one is very lengthier for me.

Comment: Added an edit with example NVL:s using the log3 cursor from the question.

Comment: Thanks Klas, it works for me, may be i did something wrong earlier.

Comment: Can any one give me the example for how can i use for NVL function for long and double datatype.

Comment: `NVL` is SQL and is performed on SQL data types. Both `long` and `double` in c are mapped against the SQL `NUMBER` data type, so the `NVL` in both cases would be `NVL(G, 0)`.

Comment: Thanks klas, Actually the problem is that there is a field called G whose type is 'decimal(15,0)'. I have taken a variable of 'long' type, in which i fetch the value of G. At the time of fetching G, it gives me sql error-1455.

Comment: Looks like your `long` is only 32 bits (~10 digits). Try the `long long` data type. It is usually at least 64 bits and should be able to hold ~20 digits.